# How to find common values in list using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
names

  year      name
0 1990 'a', 'b', 'c'
1 2001 'a', 'd', 'c'
2 2004 'e', 'b', 'c'
```

And I want to find the common values in names such that,

```
c:3, a:2, b:2, d:1, e:1
```

I am not sure how to approach this. 

But what I thought of is to convert the name column to a list:

```
names_list = name['name'].tolist()
names_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'c']
```

And then, use the below function I found in another post to get the most common value:

```
def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

most_common(names_list)
'c'
```

And it only gives one most common value, but I'm trying to get at least the top 3 values from the list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `mode` after `split` and `explode`

```
df.name.str.split(', ').explode().mode()
```

Return the count

```
df.name.str.split(', ').explode().value_counts() # if only would like the highest count , 
#df.name.str.split(', ').explode().value_counts().sort_values().tail(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, but is there a way to get names with counts? It only gives me one value and no counts how many time it appeared in the list.

Comment: @sarahkim change the mode to _value_counts

Comment: I didn't know about explode() function, I was using an older version of pandas.. but now I learned, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
names_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'c']
```

then you might use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) following way:

```
import collections
names_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'c']
occurs = collections.Counter(names_list)
print(occurs)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Note that `collections.Counter` is subclass of `dict`, so `occurs` has `.keys()`, `.values()`, `.items()` and so on.

Comment: you might have to split the list first (*for this solution to work*)